# Javascript: Get a variable name as a string using 'defined' predicate

Tags: javascript

## My use case is the following :

```
FlexboxStyle: {
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: // need a string value like 'flexEnd'
}
```

I would like to get the string value of a variable's name but with some constraints, the **less verbose** possible.

I already know that you can get the string of an existing variable using the first value returned by the `.keys()` method of `Object` :

```
var name = Object.keys({ myVariable })[0]

console.log(name) // 'myVariable'
```

Saying that, if you know a more elegant way to do this part, I'm in !

---

The following code isn't working but is a good way to express my needs :

```
FlexboxStyle: {
  ...
  justifyContent: Object.keys({ flexEnd } || { distanceBetween } || ...)[0]
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that `{ undefined_variable }` would trigger an error. And only the needed one is defined.

Fortunately for me, all those variables are gathered inside an object `props`, allowing me to use a helper function. **Here's a workaround**, but I'm really looking for a pretty one line code solution or a better one than the following :

```
const helpingFunction = (props, researchedKeys, defaultValue) => {
  researchedKeys.forEach(function (key) {
    if (props.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return key
    }
  })
  return defaultValue
}

FlexboxStyle: {
  ...
  justifyContent: helpingFunction(definedVariables, ['flexEnd', 'distanceBetween', ...], 'flexStart')
}
```

---

### TL:DR;

### 1. Is there a better/prettier way to get the following result ? :

> ```
> var name = Object.keys({ myVariable })[0]
>
> console.log(name) // 'myVariable'
> ```

### 2. Does a working similar code work to avoid using a helping function ? :

> ```
> justifyContent: Object.keys({ flexEnd } || { distanceBetween } || ...)[0]
> ```

Comment: Use Object.keys to get an array of keys and intersect that with the researchedkeys - array1.filter(value => -1 !== array2.indexOf(value)); is one way, and you could make a .intersect function for this using Array.prototype... then grab the first one with [0] as before?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "variable names" in code. Names are meaningless and static anyway. Just use a string.

If however you want to check which of a few properties exists in an object, you can just do

```
['flexEnd', 'distanceBetween', ...].find(name => name in this.props) || 'flexStart'
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                       or whatever the object is
```